# Missing assemblies that i can't include

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, assemblies, .net-assembly

For my project I need the types `vector` and `polygon`. I have found on MSDN that I had to include `WindowsBase` in my project (See below), but that doesn't work.

```
using System.Windows
using System.Windows.Windowsbase
```

Where can I find the right assembly to include?

Can I not add them as it is a windows phone project?

I have read on the internet that several other people had this problem too.

The complete error is `Error    1   The type or namespace name 'Vector' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include desktop WPF references in an application compiled for Windows Phone 7 (see [supported platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.aspx) on MSDN).

You'd better rewrite that code (or "grab" it with a decompiler keeping namespaces unchanged, in case someday it'll be shipped in a [Portable Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: So if I want to use a vector type XNA is my only solution ><. I ll finally try it ^^

Comment: Yes, not everything can be used everywhere but they're pushing a lot to make things uniform across devices. If you just need Vector struct I think you may decompile it and include source code (with same namespace), someday it'll may be available so you'll just need to remove your code. If you need graphics too (shapes and so on) then XNA may be your solution.